# Python trying to remove all occurences of an element in an array with a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm trying to remove all elements whose text property is equal to "PayLivery" from an array called "prices".

I'm new to python and don't understand why this code doesn't work:

```py
for i in range(len(prices)):
    if prices[i].text == "PayLivery":
        prices.pop(i)
        i-=1
```

The array(prices) has a length of 37 at the beginning. It throws a "Index Error list index out of range" error at an i value of 25 and a (prices)length of 25.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way to achieve what you want is to use a filtering comprehension:

```py
prices = [p for p in prices if p.text != "PayLivery"]
```

The reason your code isn't working is because the `-=` operator during any one loop has no effect on the value of `i` on the subsequent loop since the value of `i` is set by the `for` loop at the start of each loop. Here's a quick demo:

```py
>>> for i in range(5):
...     print(i)
...     i += 853718234
...
0
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: @bananalord were you helped by my answer? If so, please mark it as correct so that your question can be removed from the unanswered queue.